# secure-file-priv preventing INTO OUTFILE command

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv, load-data-infile

I'm using:

`SELECT * FROM accounts INTO OUTFILE("C:/Users/Home/Documents/test.txt")`

but I get the error:

```
(db:1290) The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
```

I don't have permission to change the security settings of the database but was wondering if there was some alternative command that would work around this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your MySQL server's config, put this line under the `[mysqld]` and restart the Service

```
secure_file_priv=/tmp/ #the dir you want to put the result file
```

Or

```
mysql -s -e 'SELECT * FROM accounts' | cat > /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. The [MySQL secure-file-priv option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_secure-file-priv) limits the directory from which you can read (or to which you can write) using LOAD DATA INFILE or SELECT INTO OUTFILE.

You can use the following command to show the allowed directory :

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv"
```

Then you should point your export to this directory.

Comment: I don't have permissions to write to that directory